# How can I send a image into Discord API request content

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, discord, fetch

I've created a simple JS code to send a message into a Discord server without using Discord.JS or other libs to create bots, I'm just trying to send a message using my actual profile.
It's working really good but I would like to upgrade it and send a image with the text too, but how can I "blob"/"embed" (sorry, I don't know what's the most appropriated word for it) the image?

Like this example above:
[Discord image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKw4j.png)

The most far I got was sending the image but it was appearing to download it, and not "auto showing" it. (Image above)
[Download image discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxdrb.png)

My code is above:

```
message = "Just a simple test message.";
token = "HERE_THE_AUTH_TOKEN_GOES";
channel_id = "HERE_THE_CHANNEL_ID_GOES";
channel_url = `https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/${channel_id}/messages`

request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.withCredentials = true;
request.open("POST", channel_url);
request.setRequestHeader("authorization", token);
request.setRequestHeader("accept", "/");
request.setRequestHeader("authority", "discordapp.com");
request.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.send(JSON.stringify({ content: message }));
```

So all I wanna know is if there's a way to auto-"embed" images into a Discord message without appearing to download it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [message create request](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message-jsonform-params) accepts an `embeds` array which contains embed objects.

An [embed object](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object) can contain an [image object](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object-embed-image-structure) where you can specify a url.

In your example, you have a body object of:

```js
let body = { content: message };
```

To embed an image, you can change the body to this:

```js
let url = "https://www.example.com/example.png"
let body = { 
  content: message,
  embeds: [
    { image: { url } }
  ]
};
```